# Windows Store app - SuspensionManager

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, application-lifecycle

I started to create a Windows Store App. From Windows Desktop applications I'am used to created several projects to structure my solution. However, I created two projects e.g. AppX and AppY. In both projects I wanted to create pages. AppX would be my entry point or start project and from AppX I can navigate to AppY.

Visual Studio adds a folder with the SuspensionManager and the NavigationHelper. I think that I use only one implementation of both. I can use the NavigationHelper class from AppY in AppX.  As the SuspensionManager is internal sealed I can not use one implementation for both projects.

What the command approach when I have more than one project with pages? Where are the SuspensionManager and the NavigationHelper? Is it even possible?

Thanks for your help.
Dani

Comment: Do you want to have **2** applications in the Windows Store? You can't have a dependency on a second application. You could just add a Windows Store Class Library Project and put your Pages in there.

Comment: A have one Windows Store app project and the second is a Class Library project but I would have pages in both projects. Probably I'll have a second Class Library Project with pages in the future.